# pygame blinking screen fix

Tags: python, pygame

My code that shows a scoreboard always blinks because of me making the background white. But I want that to stop. So is there a way to make pygame do all this drawing and filling without the display updating, and when the drawing is done it shows the new result so I don't have to see every step and thereby the blinking?

```
def score():
    while ScoreTrue:
        pygame.event.get()
        window.fill(white)
        display_score= (display_height/ 1.2)
        message_display("Scoreboard", 2, 5)
        message_meduim("5th place: " + ", ".join( repr(e) for e in Scoreboard[0] ), 3, display_score)
        message_meduim("4th place:" + ", ".join( repr(e) for e in Scoreboard[1]), 3, display_score - 100)
        message_meduim("3rd place:" + ", ".join( repr(e) for e in Scoreboard[2]), 3, display_score - 200)
        message_meduim("2nd place:" + ", ".join( repr(e) for e in Scoreboard[3]), 3, display_score - 300)
        message_meduim("1st place:" + ", ".join( repr(e) for e in Scoreboard[4]), 3, display_score - 400)
        Button("Play again", display_width/1.2,display_height/1.6, display_width/8, display_height/9, red, red_light, "play")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a while loop that displays your window(which i assume you do), then your probably calling either `pygame.display.flip()` in the loop or `pygame.display.update()`. So you should not have to call `pygame.display.update()` in your score function too. Remove the `pygame.display.update()` in your `score` function and just call the `score` function in your while loop.